# Problems exporting CorelDraw X7 file to JPG

Tags: export, corel-draw, jpg

When I export the CorelDraw X7 file to JPG I am getting an extra margin to the right and left of my graphic file. Any suggestions on how to get rid of this? [image]

Answer (score 2):

I feel that you are exporting a small image in pixels.

That would be the result of anti-aliasing the image.

1. In the View Menu, Select Pixels as view mode.
2. Zoom a lot to the problematic edge and you will see this aliasing. Move your object so you align this to this grid.
3. Export.

---

A quick fix is to export your image at let's say 4 times your desired size. For example, a 300px image can be exported to 1200px and then resampled with Nearest Neighbour to the desired size. This will eliminate this edge completely.

This 4x image can be exported without anti-aliasing.

You can experiment with a 2x or 3x too with the downscaling with anti-aliasing turned on too, this will give you different aliasing levels.

Answer (score 0):

The white is part of the image so you'll need to remove it. The crop tool is the best option, imo.

Comment: Although your answer is technically correct, it sounds as if the OP created the image in Corel Draw originally, and then is getting an outline when s/he exports it to a jpg.  A more useful answer would explain why the Corel Draw image has a border and how to get rid of it within Corel Draw before exporting.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, magerber, I'll keep that in mind. Unfortunately, without a good screenshot or more information about the processes used, that's not very feasible. Based on the fact that the line is only on the left and right, I do not believe it was some random outline, but more likely the design was slightly more narrow than the raster image it was covered into. Not much to do about that but crop the pixels.